# Question (basic) about topology and collections of subsets

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to understanding something very basic about topology.

If $X = \{a,b,c\},$ then these are some topologies on $X$:

The topology containing $X, \emptyset, \{a\}, \{a,b\}$; the topology containing $X, \emptyset, \{a,b\}$ and the one containing $X, \emptyset, \{b\}.$

But why isn't the following collection of subsets also topologies on $X$:

$X, \emptyset, \{a\}, \{b\}$ and $X, \emptyset, \{a,b\}, \{b,c\}$?

Looking at those final two examples, isn't is so that both the empty set and the space $X$ are included in the collection, that the union of sets is in the collection as well as the intersection? Shouldn't it then be a topology?

Comment: The first isn’t closed under unions: $\{a\}$ and $\{b\}$ are in the collection, but $\{a\}\cup\{b\}=\{a,b\}$ is not. The second isn’t closed under finite intersections: $\{a,b\}$ and $\{b,c\}$ are in the collection, but $\{a,b\}\cap\{b,c\}=\{b\}$ is not.

Comment: That was a very clear explanation, thank you!

Comment: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The topology $\big\{X, \varnothing, \{a\}, \{b\}\big\}$ is not closed under unions since $\{a\} \cup \{b\} = \{a, b\}$ is not in the topology. The other topology is not closed under (finite, though it doesn't matter in this case) intersections.